# Quickbooks web connector bad ticket error

Tags: quickbooks

I had a working setup of desktop QuickBooks and PHP web application. I am facing **Bad Ticket** error while running quickbooks web connector, I queued one request in the ***quickbooks_queue*** table. Connector authentication is successful but when it tries to read first request it sends Bad Ticket error and ends the process.

I am running the **example_app_web_connector** example from build (***build_20130416***)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was already answered over here:

- http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7945

The bottom line is you're using an SQL table schema from a previous version of the code you're using, with a newer version of the code. The SQL table schemas are not compatible across the two versions of code you're trying to use.

Drop all of your `quickbooks_*` SQL tables, and let the code re-create them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I asked my developer team for this issue, here is a manual provided by Intuit to solve this error - https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBWC_proguide.pdf

Comment: my sendRequestXML is blank. I don't know why. It is not coming into my request function which I have mapped for QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER